# Perl Script broken after upgrade to 5.8.8

Tags: mysql, perl

We have a old application that works fine using Perl-5.8.5.8 but does not work any more on Perl-5.8.8, I'm sure its a simple change but I can't find it.

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Unknown column 'stores.id' in 'on clause' at /var/www/cgi-bin/app/list.cgi line 70
```

This is the context of line 70

```
my $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();   ################Line 70
```

Here is the complete program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
do "share.pl";

sub get_propertytable {
        my ($id, $devicename) = @_;
        my $content = "<table><tr><th colspan=2>$devicename $id</th></tr>";
        my $sql = "SELECT propertytypes.propertyname, deviceproperties.propertyvalue FROM deviceproperties INNER JOIN propertytypes ON deviceproperties.propertytype = propertytyp$
        my $sthq = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sthq->execute();
        $sthq->bind_columns(\$propname, \$propvalue);
        while ($sthq->fetch()){
                if ($propname !~ /"Connected"/){
                $content .= "<tr><td>$propname</td><td>: $propvalue</td></tr>";}
        }
    $content .= "</table>";
}

sub get_storetable {
        my $id = @_[0];
        my $content = "<table><tr><th colspan=2>Store $id</th></tr>";
        my $sql = "SELECT storename,address,postcode,phoneno FROM stores WHERE id=$id";
        my $sthq = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sthq->execute();
        my ($storename, $address, $postcode, $phoneno);
        $sthq->bind_columns(\$storename, \$address, \$postcode, \$phoneno);
        $sthq->fetch();    
        $address =~ s/,/<br>/g;
        my $content = "<table><tr><th colspan=2>$storename</th></tr>";
        $content .= "<tr><td valign=top>Address :</td><td>$address</td></tr>";
        $content .= "<tr><td>Post Code :</td><td>$postcode</td></tr>";
        $content .= "<tr><td>Phone No :</td><td>$phoneno</td></tr>";
        $content .= "</table>";
}

sub get_franchisetable {
        my $id = @_[0];
        if ($id){
        my $content = "<table><tr><th colspan=2>Franchise $id</th></tr>";
        my $sql = "SELECT contactname,company,contactno,email FROM Franchisees WHERE id=$id";
        my $sthq = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sthq->execute();
        my ($contactname, $company, $contactno, $email);
        $sthq->bind_columns(\$contactname, \$company, \$contactno, \$email);
        $sthq->fetch();
        $address =~ s/,/<br>/g;
        my $content = "<table><tr><th colspan=2>$company</th></tr>";
        $content .= "<tr><td valign=top>Contact Name :</td><td>$contactname</td></tr>";
        $content .= "<tr><td>Contact No :</td><td>$contactno</td></tr>";
        $content .= "<tr><td>Email :</td><td>$email</td></tr>";
        $content .= "</table>";
        }
}

if ( valid_user() == 1 ) {

my $sql = "SELECT id,devicename FROM devicetypes";
my $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$sth->bind_columns(\$id, \$devicename);
while ($sth->fetch()){
        $devicetypes[$id] = $devicename;
}
$sth->finish();

my $sql = "SELECT stores.id, stores.storename, devices.id,devices.devicetype,tradingpartner.name,tradingpartner.id
FROM stores,storetradingpartner,tradingpartner
LEFT JOIN devices ON devices.store = stores.id
WHERE stores.id = storetradingpartner.storeid
AND tradingpartner.id = storetradingpartner.partnerid
ORDER BY tradingpartner.name,stores.storename,devices.devicetype,devices.id";
my $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();   ################# Line 70
#$sth->bind_columns(\$storeid, \$store, \$deviceid, \$devicetype, \$tradingpartner, \$partnerid);

print "Content-type: text/html

<body link='#000000' vlink='#000000' alink='#000000'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/clit/wz_tooltip.js\" language='javascript'>
</script>
<SCRIPT SRC=\"/clit/getpropertytable.js\">
</SCRIPT>

<script language='javascript' type=\"text/javascript\">
function hidediv(thediv) {
        if (document.getElementById(thediv).style.display == 'none'){
                document.getElementById(thediv).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
                document.getElementById(thediv).style.display = 'none';
        }
    return 0;
}


//</script>
<font face=arial>
<h1>Asset List</h1>
<a href=index.cgi>Back to ticket list</a>
<br><br>
```

Comment: The error message implies you have a schema mismatch. As well as changing Perl versions, have you moved to another machine, or rebuilt the database?

Comment: I'm terrified of the world in which Perl 5.8.8 is considered an upgrade.

Comment: write a simple perl to use DBI and make sure it works

Comment: There is no `Perl 5.8.5.8`. Do you mean you're upgrading `5.8.5` to `5.8.8` (which is July 2004 to January 2006)?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the pointers and help, remarks...

Comment: @Borodin This is probably 5.8.5-8, probably the perl package which comes with RedHat EL4. 5.8.8 is part of EL5, which is still [supported by RedHat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#Life-cycle_dates).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm suspecting you have upgraded to a newer MySQL server version, too.

Queries like this:

```
FROM stores, storetradingpartner, tradingpartner
LEFT JOIN devices ON devices.store = stores.id
```

are parsed differently, I believe, as of MySQL <strike>4.0</strike> 5.0.12. You should avoid mixing implicit joins (e.g. `table, table2, table3`) with explicit joins (like `LEFT JOIN`).

Try this:

```
FROM stores
INNER JOIN storetradingpartner ON stores.id = storetradingpartner.storeid
INNER JOIN tradingpartner ON tradingpartner.id = storetradingpartner.partnerid
LEFT JOIN devices ON devices.store = stores.id
ORDER BY...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html:

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes interpretation of what those operands are.

Note that there were other join changes in 5.0.1 and 5.0.12 to bring MySQL more in line with the SQL standard, some of which will result in differences in rows returned, not just produce errors as in this case.

Comment: My money's on @ysth being right - that's a MySQL error and nothing to do with Perl. Tip for future readers - if possible upgrade *one thing at a time*. If not, make sure you know *what* has changed. I know I've  struggled with similar issues often enough.

Comment: @Richard Huxton: It is *absolutely* a database error. The MySQL driver `DBD::mysql` is reporting `Unknown column`. That is way beyond Perl's jurisdiction.

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm basically trying to migrate a server running CentOS 4.9 to CentOS 5.10. Everything else works apart from something on this script. I did upgrade Mysql, even other scripts involving mysql and perl work without any issues.

Comment: TTTTTTTTTTTTTTAAAAAANNNNNNNK YOU·

Comment: @Ysth Thank you Ysth, help a lot to sort out the issue I had, Most of the things I tried work exactly as it did not CentOS 4.9  -  I'm new on this forum don't know yet how to change my username, will do soon.

Comment: @Dave Cross - Hi , nothing wrong with 6.4, we moving from a dedicate server to Amazon, We used to run the system on a RHEL 4.8 dedicated server, I managed to upload everything to AWS and use it unders CentOS 4.9. The last step I did was upgrade this server to CentOS 5-10, the people that develop the system didn’t leave any documentation. So will be more complicate to port it to 6.4